# Why Projection Matrices are singular

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I know the formal proof of the fact that a Projection Matrix is singular. From which it follows that the only invertible projection is the identity.

But I still don't understand intuitively why. I know that a singular matrix carries parallelepipeds into lines, but why a singular transformation must have $det = 0?$

Comment: What does determinant mean to you? I know you have a formula, but that doesn't mean anything to anyone, that's just a recipe for calculation. What does "determinant" _mean_ to you? Or, more specifically, what does "determinant is $0$" mean to you?

Comment: That carries parallelipipedes into lines

Comment: @Rahul Yes, will remove my comment!

Comment: @Qwerto But the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ takes parallelepipedes to parallelograms (or hexagons), not lines, and it still has determinant $0$. So something is off about your understanding here.

Comment: @Arthur there is nothing wrong with the understanding here. Determinants tell us how much does a matrix  stretches and rotates, and when it is zero in a 2D space, this means the area squishes to zero (resulting in a line or a point). But in 3D (3x3 matrix), the volumes will shrink to zero, and therefore the resultant transformation can be either a plane, a line or a point.

Comment: @Math1995 That's a lot more detailed than "That carries parallelepipeds to lines". Your explanation illustrates a good understanding of the determinant. The above comment by the OP doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

A projection matrix $P$ is a projection, when it fulfills $PPx=Px$. 
This is the same as saying "If I project twice, it doesn't change a thing the second time".
Assuming, that this matrix $P$ has an inverse, you arrive at $Px=x$ which only holds true for the identity $I$.

Another way to see it, is given by the geometric interpretation. In a projection, you always loose dimensions. Your shadow is a 2D-projection of your 3D body. When you loose a dimension, you loose information and the transformation can not be undone.

Answer (score 1):

One « geometrical » way to prove that the determinant of a projection $p$ vanishes is to remember that for a basis $(e_1, \dots,e_n)$ you have for any linear map $u$ the relationship

$$Vol(u(e_1), \dots, u(e_n))= \det(u) Vol(e_1, \dots, e_n)$$

where $Vol$ designates the volume of the parallelepipede based on the vectors.

For a projection, the volume $Vol(p(e_1), \dots, p(e_n))$ vanishes as all the images of the basis $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ are in a proper subspace. Hence $\det(p)=0$.